# How to deconstruct a list and add it to a data frame as row in r

Tags: r

I've recieved some data in a form of a very convulauted excel sheet and was able to rearrange it as a list of n objects, each object has y arrays in it (Let's call them a,b,c). some don't hold all the arrays (a = c("1","2"), b = NULL, c = c("A","B",C")

```
mylist <- list (a = c("1","2"), b = NULL, c = c("A","B","C"))
```

I want to take the first element from each array and add it to a row in a data frame like so:

```
df
[1] "1", NULL, "A"
```

I've tried using the list2env function but when it comes to the NULL it for some reason fails to create the variable and append it to the data frame.

Also I will be dealing with longer and longer objects and would like to find a way to add it automatically - if I use the list2env function I have to add them manually.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` and then `rbind` the retuned list and transform it to a `data.frame` using `as.data.frame` like:

```
(df <- as.data.frame(rbind(lapply(mylist, "[[", 1))))
#  a    b c
#1 1 NULL A
```

In case its OK to replace the `NULL` with `"NULL"` or `NA` you can use:

```
sapply(replace(mylist, mylist=="NULL", "NULL"), "[[", 1)
#     a      b      c 
#   "1" "NULL"    "A" 

sapply(replace(mylist, mylist=="NULL", NA), "[[", 1)
#  a   b   c 
#"1"  NA "A"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for trying to help!! I tried this and for some reason I end up with a weird object that has lists as the columns. so it looks good when I just try to view it as an output but when I try to extract to a CSV with write.csv or any other output function it fails with "Error in write.table(df, "CSV1.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'". any thoughts on reasons for this behaviour? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The problem is the `NULL`. The only way I know is the create a `data.frame` who's columns are `lists` to hold also `NULL`. E.g. `data.frame(a=1, b=NULL, c="A")` does not work. Is it OK to convert the `NULL` to an `NA`?

Comment: Sure (Adding more characters because the system if forcing me and won't post comment without)